# Installing peewee without vcvarsall.bat

Tags: windows, python-2.7, anaconda, peewee

I just installed Anaconda with Python 2.7.13 on Windows 7 from a binary, and now I want to install peewee 2.8.0.  The error says:

```
skipping 'playhouse\speedups.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'playhouse._speedups' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Does this mean that Cython is included in Anaconda and so peewee tries to build the speedups extension?  I installed Visual C++ 2010 Express, but that did not help.  Is there a way to install peewee without the speedups extension, and would that get around the problem?

Comment: Try the index of [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). No need to compile locally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, right after I posted the question, I opened peewee setup.py and forced cython_installed = False.  Now it installs successfully.